# Reading from InputStream as an Iterator[Byte] or Array[Byte]

Tags: scala, byte, inputstream, type-conversion

I am representing a data object as an `Iterator[Byte]`, which is created from an `InputStream` instance.

The problem lies in that `Byte` is a signed integer from -128 to 127, while the `read` method in `InputStream` returns an unsigned integer from 0 to 255. This is in particular problematic since by semantics -1 should denote the end of an input stream.

What is the best way to alleviate the incompatibility between these two types? Is there an elegant way of converting between one to another? Or should I just use `Int` instead of `Bytes`, even though it feels less elegant?

```
def toByteIterator(in: InputStream): Iterator[Byte] = {
  Iterator.continually(in.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).map { elem =>
    convert // need to convert unsigned int to Byte here
  }
}

def toInputStream(_it: Iterator[Byte]): InputStream = {
  new InputStream {
    val (it, _) = _it.duplicate
    override def read(): Int = {
      if (it.hasNext) it.next() // need to convert Byte to unsigned int
      else -1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what about  byte b=(byte)intValue-128;

Comment: It seems rather unintuitive esp. to those who are not familiar that such problem even exists. I would like to avoid that if possible, since due to the nature and scale of the data I'm dealing with, it is _very_ hard to recover the data once it is corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can convert byte to int and vice versa easily.

First, int to byte can be converted with just `toByte`:

```
scala> 128.toByte
res0: Byte = -128

scala> 129.toByte
res1: Byte = -127

scala> 255.toByte
res2: Byte = -1
```

so your `elem => convert` could be just `_.toByte`.

Second, a signed byte can be converted to an unsigned `int` with a handy function in `java.lang.Byte`, called [`toUnsignedInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-):

```
scala> java.lang.Byte.toUnsignedInt(-1)
res1: Int = 255

scala> java.lang.Byte.toUnsignedInt(-127)
res2: Int = 129

scala> java.lang.Byte.toUnsignedInt(-128)
res3: Int = 128
```

so you can write `java.lang.Byte.toUnsignedInt(it.next())` in your second piece of code.

However, the last method is only available since Java 8. I don't know about its alternatives in older versions of Java, but its actual implementation is astonishingly simple:

```
public static int toUnsignedInt(byte x) {
    return ((int) x) & 0xff;
}
```

so all you need is just to write

```
it.next().toInt & 0xff
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is something related with a bad design of the class `InputStream`. If you use [read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) you will have that problem. You should use [read(byte[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) instead.
But as you say, you could also use `Int`. That is up to you.